# General way to convert java.sql.ResultSet to POJO using only Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, resultset

So, I have a POJO class like this one:

```
class Office {

    @Column(name = "OFFICE_ID")
    private Long officeId;

    @Column(name = "OFFICE_FI_ID")
    private Long officeFiId;
// Setters and gettes here
```

And appropriate resultSet. Usually all you need to do is create instance and for every field write down something like this:

```
office.setOfficeId(rs.getLong("OFFICE_ID"));
```

But I want to do that using reflection and ideally instead of it write

```
fetchRSintoPOJO(resultSet, Office.class);
```

My question is: can I using hibernate convert current ResultSet row into POJO without using ResultSet setLong, setString etc. methods directly, because I am using reflection and I would need to write great amount of code, for example

```
if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)){...}.
```

So, I wonder if someone did it before me.

Can you advise me something? Thank you.

Comment: If you are using hibernate, Hibernate would do that automatically for you. Why are you using resultSet? Use HQL or Hibernate Criteria to query the database?

Comment: because we don't use hql, we use stored procedures

Comment: You can call stored procedures from hibernate as well. What is the use of hibernate if you are not at all using it. Anyway, see below links to know how to execute stored procedure from hibernate

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1005839

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can easily convet `POJO` from `Query`. But to convert from `Resultset` try with following way

```
while(resultSet.next()){
 office=new Office();
 office.setOfficeId(resultSet.getLong("OFFICE_ID"));
 ......
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I know I can do that, and you could understand that from my question. From your answer I assume you were confused by phrase "convert resultset to POJO". Ok, if you like it more, in the end I want to get list of POJO objects. But my question is not about it. My question is: can I using hibernate convert current ResultSet row into POJO without using ResultSet setLong, setString etc. methods directly, because I am using reflection and I would need to write great amount of code,for example if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)){...}. So, I wonder if someone did it before me

Comment: I don't think, that is available in Hibernate.